# How to insert space in text in a .PDF file created via ".R" -> (roxygen2) ".Rd" -> (R CMD check mypackage) ".PDF"?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, spaces, roxygen2

I already created many .PDF files via ".R" -> (roxygen2) ".Rd" -> (R CMD check mypackage) ".PDF".

Now, I wanted to add a table template in .PDF file of the package (mypackage-manual.pdf):

```
Table: ADF Statistics of the Raw Variables
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  var type inc levelt Pc c Pt t prob omlo type inc 1stDifft Pc c Pt t prob omlo intorder
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1 Var1 dt                                  dt
2 Var1 d                                   d
3 Var1 -                                   -
4 Var2 dt                                  dt
5 Var2 d                                   d
6 Var2 -                                   -
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**What I did:**
**1.** I pressed to spacebar lots of times to allocate enough spaces so that "dt"/"d"/"-" are placed under the type column. 
But, upon [".R" -> (roxygen2) ".Rd" -> (R CMD check package) ".PDF"] process, these spaces did not appear as if I did not pressed spacebar at all!

**2.** I inserted lots of "\quad" tags to produce enough spaces in the preamble of ".R" file:

```
#' Table: ADF Statistics of the Raw Variables \cr
#' -------------------------------------------------- \cr
#'   var type inc levelt Pc c Pt t prob omlo type inc 1stDifft Pc c Pt t prob omlo intorder \cr
#' ------------------------------------------------------------------ \cr
#' 1 Var1 dt\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad dt \cr
#' 2 Var1 d \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad d \cr
#' 3 Var1 - \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad - \cr
#' 4 Var2 dt \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad dt \cr
#' 5 Var2 d \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad d \cr
#' 6 Var2 - \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad - \cr
#' -------------------------------------------------------------------- \cr
```

But, upon [".R" -> (roxygen2) ".Rd" -> (R CMD check package) ".PDF"] process, all of these "\quad" tags were not processed, and all of them was printed in the resultant .PDF as if they are text, not tags:

```
Table: ADF Statistics of the Raw Variables 
--------------------------------------------------
   var type inc levelt Pc c Pt t prob omlo type inc 1stDifft Pc c Pt t prob omlo intorder 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 1 Var1 dt\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad dt 
 2 Var1 d \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad d 
 3 Var1 - \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad - 
 4 Var2 dt \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad dt 
 5 Var2 d \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad d 
 6 Var2 - \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad - 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As a newbee to latex, I could not achieve to put enough spaces. Also, I am not sure whether "being a newbee to latex" and "peculiar code required by roxygen2" is my deficiency. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**3.** Thomas' solution (as far as I can apply):

```
#'  \tabular{ccccccccccccccccccccc}{
#'    . \tab var \tab type \tab inc \tab levelt \tab Pc \tab c \tab Pt \tab t \tab prob \tab omlo \tab type \tab inc \tab 1stDifft \tab Pc \tab c \tab Pt \tab t \tab prob \tab omlo \tab intorder \cr
#'    1 \tab Var1 \tab dt \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab dt \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \cr
#'    2 \tab Var1 \tab d \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab d \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \cr
#'    3 \tab Var1 \tab - \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab - \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \cr
#'    4 \tab Var2 \tab dt \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab dt \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \cr
#'    5 \tab Var2 \tab d \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab d \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \cr
#'    6 \tab Var2 \tab - \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab - \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab
#'  }
```

did this:

```
. var type inc levelt Pc c Pt t prob omlo type inc 1stDifft Pc c Pt t prob oml
1 Var1 dt                                  dt
2 Var1 d                                    d
3 Var1 -                                    -
4 Var2 dt                                  dt
5 Var2 d                                    d
6 Var2 -                                    -
```

The column names did not fit into right side of .PDF at the end, and "o intorder" was not shown in the resultant .PDF.

Comment: Take a look here for instructions on tables: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Lists-and-tables. In LaTeX, most whitespace is basically ignored.

Comment: @Thomas Your solution (using `\tabular` and `\tab`) solves the problem to some extent. I applied the table code in [link](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Lists-and-tables). The tabs are separating much, hence, thinking "inc levelt Pc c Pt t prob omlo" to be in the same column is a solution to much-separation. A solution without using `\tabular` and `\tab` would be very elastic; I do not struggle for formal coding, but any coding (reflecting better appearance) in the .PDF file.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the new `\tabular` code that you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#'
#' Table: ADF Statistics of the Raw Variables \cr
#' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \cr
#'  \tabular{cl}{
#'    . \tab var type inc levelt Pc c Pt t prob omlo type inc 1stDifft Pc c Pt t prob omlo intorder \cr
#'    1 \tab Var1 dt ................................................. dt .................. \cr
#'    2 \tab Var1 d ................................................. d .................. \cr
#'    3 \tab Var1 - ................................................. - .................. \cr
#'    4 \tab Var2 dt ................................................. dt .................. \cr
#'    5 \tab Var2 d ................................................. d .................. \cr
#'    6 \tab Var2 - ................................................. - ..................
#'  }
#' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \cr
#'
```

produced:

```
Table: ADF Statistics of the Raw Variables
————————————————————————————–
. var type inc levelt Pc c Pt t prob omlo type inc 1stDifft Pc c Pt t prob omlo intorder
1 Var1 dt ................................. dt ..................
2 Var1 d .................................. d ..................
3 Var1 - .................................. - ..................
4 Var2 dt ................................. dt ..................
5 Var2 d .................................. d ..................
6 Var2 - .................................. - ..................
————————————————————————————–
```

I tried `xcolor` package and its derivatives to make dots appear white, but it failed.